# Eclipse Plugin - How to contribute to a menu on the editor?

Tags: user-interface, menu, eclipse-plugin

Currently my plugin.xml has

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
```

Which contributes to the menu showed when right clicking some file in the project explorer.

**In addition**, I want to contribute to the menu showed when right clicking anywhere in the editor view (the view with the code itself).

I can't find what's the corresponding extension point for this menu, and how do I contribute to two different menus.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus` extension point is deprecated and should not be used for new code.

The `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point supports all types of menu.

You define a `popup` style menu using something like:

```xml
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:org.eclipse.pde.ui.tools">
   ... various menu contributions
```

The `locationURI` is saying this contribution to the popup menu with id `org.eclipse.pde.ui.tools`

You must define the id of your editor's context menu in your editor code. How you do this defines on the type of editor your are creating. For an editor based on `TextEditor` call

```java
setEditorContextMenuId("menu id");
```

in your editor's constructor.